# How to "blend/merge" two images usingi an objective-c library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm wondering if there is some image manipulation library that will allow me to take two images and blend them together. Or blend together parts of images in a mosaic so that it doesn't look like its a mosaic, but is one whole image.

I've looked on google code and searched for such a library, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alpha blending is directly supported by the Quartz graphics engine, so you don't need any additional libraries. You just draw one image, then draw the second image with an alpha of less than 1.0 on top of it. Read the UIImage and Core Graphics documentation for details.